# psql doesn't prompt for password and throws wrong password error

Tags: postgresql, windows, psql, postgresql-15

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL 15 on my desktop at work (Windows 10). When installing, everything goes fine and I set a password to the default postgres user.

Using `psql -U postgres` on PowerShell, it throws this error message BEFORE prompting me to enter a password:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

In the `pg_hba.conf` file, all `METHOD` values are set to `scram-sha-256`. Changing to `md5` and `password` doesn't help. It only works when I change it to `trust`, but I wanted to have a password. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As far as I'm aware, I don't. I even tried to search within `%appdata%` for the file, but there's no `postgresql` folder there, only a `pgAdmin` folder.

Comment: What do get if you run `echo %PGPASSWORD%`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I get only `%PGPASSWORD%`. It was supposed to be set on PATH?

Comment: But anyways, thanks for the help. Forcing to prompt for password using -W fixed it. But I can't wrap my mind around why it doesn't ask for a password if I've set everything by default.

Comment: Apparently, the `runpsql.bat` script was missing the -W option to prompt for a password. Is it a bug or it has always been like this?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what your `runpsql.bat` is doing. And the -W option should never be necessary.

Comment: runpsql.bat doesn't prompt for a password because that is the job of the "real" psql.  On my system, it prompts fine once I rename the pgpass.conf file so it can't be found anymore under the expected name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add -W flag to force prompt for password
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-psql.html

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Why is it that by default it isn't asking for the password? Weird.

Comment: psql is usually used in scripts and passwords managed via .pgpass. One does not want server scripts to wait for someone to enter password :D